# Pragma table info for ObjectBox

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox, greenrobot-objectbox

I am using ObjectBox for the flutter project. I want to get the pragma table info for the my **Product** Entity. Anyone know how to get the pragma for particular Entity?

Like in sqlite `pragma table_info('albums');`

```
cid  name      type           notnull  dflt_value  pk
---  --------  -------------  -------  ----------  --
0    AlbumId   INTEGER        1                    1
1    Title     NVARCHAR(160)  1                    0
2    ArtistId  INTEGER        1                    0
```

we can get the table details. I want same in ObjectBox.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by pragma? Note that ObjectBox is not a traditional SQL database, but a key value store. Also the model is defined by annotating classes and operations are exposed by an API, not a query language. https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started

Comment: Like in sql we get table's column name using  this query "pragma table_info('Product');", I want same in objectbox.

Comment: Such an API doesn't exist, as said ObjectBox is not a traditional relational database. However, the [model JSON file](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/meta-model-ids-and-uids#json-for-consistent-ids) (`lib/objectbox-model.json`) contains some of the information you want. What do you want to do with this info?